# making Sum by value of Row in access

Tags: sql

I have a problem by counting by row in my database.
I have a table with 2 columns: 2011 with its values and 2012 with its values and total column:
  table Books:

```
 2011 2012  TOTAL
   1    2     ?
   6    9     ?
   4   10     ?
  56   12     ?
```

how can I `sum(1+2), sum (6+9)` and write the results in the "TOTAL"-column for each row?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`SUM` aggregate function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/sum-function-HP001032274.aspx) ?

Comment: i tried but iti gives me the wrong result

Comment: What does _wrong result_ mean? And what results do you expect? Can you please edit the question to elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward, do not use `SUM()`

```
SELECT year1, year2, (year1 + year2) AS Total
FROM   tableName
```

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    Total = (year1 + year2)
```

Comment: was just **`answering`** when i got a message like **`1 New Answer`**. It was same as yours. I am a bit slow in **`Typing`** **`:P`**

Comment: your question is unclear, do you want to update? select? or what?

Comment: i want to make SUM by row and the result of the row to be first TOTAL

Comment: that's what i did right? can you show your desired output please?